# $S_n=\sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^{\Omega(q_k)}\cdot{q_k}$ change sign infinitely many times?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, conjectures

Let $q_k$ be the k-$th$ positive natural number that is divisible by a square larger than one. How to prove that

$S_n=\sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^{\Omega(q_k)}\cdot{q_k}$ change sign infinitely many times as $n$ increases?

$\Omega(n)$ is the number of (not necessarily different) prime factors of $n$.

I have made some numerical experiments that indicates this conjecture.

Adequate answers will be rewarded with bounties.

Comment: The community should bump this question to the homepage after being abandoned for over a year.